# When using recursion in C#, is the code processed linearly or in pseudo parallel?

Tags: c#, recursion, fork

I'm currently writing a program in C#, a language I'm not too familiar with, and I've been noticing some unexpected values when using recursion. My question is, when using recursion in C#, are the function calls thrown on the stack and processed like in Java, or does C# try and implement fork()/pthread pseudo parallelism to increase op time?

Comment: Recursion in C# does not do anything fancy at all.  What is your code?

Comment: I am currenty writing a factorial using recurse in Java, and I have to say that C# and Java syntax are not that different.  Can you share your code?

Comment: can you provide some code that produces unexpected values ?

Comment: I can't, sorry. I don't think my company would appreciate it.

I can put some pseudo code up though.

Comment: @Dino You shouldn't implement factorial recursively.  It's a horrible candidate for recursion.  A naive recursive implementation is O(2^n), a naive iterative implementation is O(n).  You can do enough work to make the recursive case not terrible (by, say, caching), but that's way more work than just using an iterative solution.

Comment: @Servy, you may be right about factorial and recursion.  I like to play with code and see how they can achive the result by considering performance and best practices.

Comment: @user3107774, how we can see the problem without code?

Comment: @Dino I can figure out if there's an issue in the code, my question was more based upon how C# is compiled.

Comment: @user3107774, as you wish.

Answer (score 6):

> or does C# try and implement fork()/pthread pseudo parallelism to
>   increase op time?

**No.** Each recursive call will be processed linearly. If you are calling your method from `Parallel.For/Parallel.Foreach` or in some other multi threaded way, then you can expect non linear execution.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about `C#` and `fork` in the same sentence is kind of weird. Although alternatives exists to run .NET on Linux, it was created for Windows, since `fork()` is a POSIX system call (a.k.a not Windows') your question lack of sense.

Besides that, there is nothing cleaver behind recursion in C#. Just normal methods calls pushed onto the stack. It doesn't even count with `tail recursion`.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the outputs I was getting were pointing to pseudo parallelism. I thought they might be implemented automatically to improve optime.

Answer (score 0):

C# does recursion just like any other C-like language: parameters get put on the stack and the method is called in order.

It is done the same way in C, C++, Java, ... besides recursion tends to be hard to parallelize because the result of call *n* tends to depend upon the results of call *n+1*.

Comment: Not all languages handle it the same way C, C++, Java do, not at all.  Also, "recursion tends to be hard to parallelize because the result of call n tends to depend upon the results of call n+1" is sometimes true, but certainly not always true.  It even has a name, a tail recursive function, when it's not the case.

Comment: @Servy: Notice the use of "tends to be". Not as in "is always". And that's all I'm going to say about this, I don't feel like another hourlong debate over half-bits.

Comment: You say that recursion tends to be hard to paralleize, yes, but you had no qualifications to the statement that C# handles recursion the same way as any other language, which is false for a great many reasons in a great many cases.  With the edit, it's fine.

Answer (score -1):

When you use recursion in C#, it is done in one thread.
Just look at your call stack in debug mode to prove it to yourself

[image]

Comment: Recursion & Threading have  nothing in common. It can be multithread + recursive. So, you can not definitely say: *it is done in one thread*. Try this for ex, **async Task<int> Fib(int num)
    {
        return await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            if (num == 0) return 0;
            if (num == 1) return 1;

            var res = await Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(()=>Fib(num - 1)), Task.Run(()=>Fib(num - 1)));
            return res[0] + res[1];
        });
    }**